# Attach Policy to AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-iam

I have made a whitelist policy containing list of IP address from where I want to get the IP

Sample below, consider Policy ARN is `arn:aws:iam::0000000:policy/Whitelister`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "W.X.Y.Z",
                        "A.B.C.D"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an AWS Elasticsearch(ES) account, which allows JSON based access policy. How can I use the above policy in AWS ES' policy to restrict access to these IPs only.

I have hard written IPs now, but that will cause redundancy and updating the IPs will be difficult.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:es:****************/domain-name/*",
        "arn:aws:es:****************/domain-name/"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "W.X.Y.Z",
            "A.B.C.D"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you **can't use** your policy in IP policy for an ES domain.

Let me elaborate a bit on this, as I think there is a confusion between **resource-based policies**, such as IP policies for the ES domain, and **identity-based policies** for IAM users, roles or groups. The differences are explained in the AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).

In short, you policy `arn:aws:iam::0000000:policy/Whitelister` is, so called, [managed-policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#aws-managed-policies). The managed polices can only be attached to `IAM identity` which can be **IAM user, group or role**. They can't be attached to resource-based policies.

Comment: thanks, can you suggest any wayaround? or do I have to hard code the IPs?

Comment: @RishiSharma Unfortunately I'm not aware of any workaround. That's how it works with resource-based policies. However, you can use security groups to achieve same goal. And one SG can be shared across several ES domain.